# PHP search array in multi dimensional

Tags: php, arrays

How to search array in that stored in multidimensional?
[image]

I want to search like this, if found then return 1;

```
search($array,23,164);//search permission with company
```

Comment: would you like some fries with that sir?

Comment: `function search($array, $company, $permission) { foreach ($array as $values) { if ($values['company'] == $company && in_array($permission, $values['permission']) { return 1; } } return 0; }`

Comment: Something you would have to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a function like this:

```
function array_seaech($array, $company_id, $permission)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value['company'] == $company_id)
            {
                foreach($value['permission'] as $keyp => $valuep)
                {
                    if($valuep == $permission)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

In this case if it found data will return true otherwise return false.

In these cases you need to Iterates over each value in the array and check those.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution :

```
$arr = [
  [
   "company"=>1,
   "permissions" => [
     10,20,30
   ]
 ],
 [
  "company" => 2,
  "permissions" => [
   3,41,5
  ]
 ]
];

function search($arr, $company_id, $perm_id) {
  return array_map(function($item) use ($company_id, $perm_id){

    if ($item['company'] == $company_id ) {
      if( array_search($perm_id, $item["permissions"]) ) {
       return $item;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }, $arr);
}

var_dump(search($arr, 2,41));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the function which works for  you

```
function in_array_r($arrayItem , $array){
    return preg_match('/"'.$arrayItem.'"/i' , json_encode($arrayName));
}
```

and this is how you call it

```
if(in_array_r($item , $array){
    // found!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use PHP >= 5.5.0, try this:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        'company'=>2,
        'permission'=>array(45,33,22),
    ),
    array(
        'company'=>6,
        'permission'=>array(21,20,76),
    ),
);

function search($array, $company, $permission)
{
    $companyValues = array_column($array, 'company');
    $permissionValues = array_column($array, 'permission');

    $combinedArray = array_combine($companyValues, $permissionValues);

    if(isset($combinedArray[$company]) && in_array($permission, $combinedArray[$company]))
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

echo search($array, 2, 33);
```

**Working demo: [CLICK!](https://eval.in/575434)**

Comment: your function is working, but unfortunately, im using <5.5.0 version

Answer (score 0):

try this simple one liner search

```
<?php

 $full_array =array('0'=>array('company'=>'23','permission'=>array('0'=>'30','1'=>'31','2'=>'164')),'1'=>array('company'=>'51','permission'=>array('0'=>'52','1'=>'80')));



     $given_company_data='23';
     $given_permission_data='31';

 $i=1;

 foreach($full_array as $row)
 {



     if($row['company']==$given_company_data && in_array($given_permission_data,$row['permission']))
    {

      echo "hi".$i;

    }

$i++;

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach: 
The idea is that we create a query array to tell the searchDeep() function how to query the array.

This can be replaced with OOP code instead of ugly arrays.

In this example we search in just one level but a recursive option should be added.

```
    // The array that you search in.
    $array[] = array(
        'company' => 23,
        'permission' => array(
            30, 31, 164
        )
    );
    $array[] = array(
        'company' => 51,
        'permission' => array(
            52, 80
        )
    );

    // Define here how to query your array.
    // More types can be added to handle objects and more complex arrays.
    $searchDef = array(
        // we can add 'orWhere' part to handle OR operand.
        'andWhere' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'keyVal',
                'key' => 'company',
                'val' => 88
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'indexedArr',
                'key' => 'permission',
                'val' => 80
            ),
        ),
    );
    $this->searchDeep($array, $searchDef);

    public function searchDeep($searchIn, $searchDef){
        $andWhere = isset($searchDef['andWhere']) ? $searchDef['andWhere'] : FALSE;
        $whereResult = FALSE;

        if($andWhere !== FALSE) {
            $first = TRUE;
            foreach ($andWhere as $whereItem) {

                // this is a 'AND' clause so if the prior where failed then no need to
                // keep checking.
                if(!$first && $whereResult === FALSE) {
                    break;
                }
                $first = FALSE;
                $type = $whereItem['type'];
                switch ($type) {
                    case "keyVal":
                        $key = $whereItem['key'];
                        $val = $whereItem['val'];
                        foreach ($searchIn as $searchItem){
                            if(isset($searchItem[$key]) && $searchItem[$key] == $val) {
                                $whereResult = TRUE;
                                break;
                            } else {
                                $whereResult = FALSE;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "indexedArr":
                        $key = $whereItem['key'];
                        $val = $whereItem['val'];

                        foreach ($searchIn as $searchItem){
                            if(isset($searchItem[$key])) {
                                $whereResult = array_search($val, $searchItem[$key]) !== FALSE ? TRUE : FALSE;
                                if($whereResult === TRUE) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            } else {
                                $whereResult = FALSE;
                            }

                        }

                        break;
                }
             }
        }
        return $whereResult;

    }
```